# What is the core difference between coin and token?

Tags: tokens, ether, bitcoin

From googling some results, both are exchanges of value

**token** is limited to the project ecosystem.
**coin** is a general-purpose exchange of value.

But I didn't get it Bitcoin is a Coin still we buy it using USD. and we can use BTC or ETH in their own ecosystems. they are not general-purpose anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coin`: L1 native asset (BTC, ETH, SOL, ADA)

`token`: asset via smart contract (ERC20, NFT, ERC1155, community tokens, social tokens, ...).

Answer (score 3):

**Coin** - is the primary medium for exchanging value in the ecosystem.It is used to reward the validators/miners 
**Token** - is a secondary medium for exchanging value in the blockchain. They are "live" in a smart contract, so in blockchain which does not support smart contract development can not have tokens.