# What is the name for a primary coin?

Tags: tokens

On chains like Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain there are coins that are like the god coins of the whole system and are used for gas. What is the name given to these types of coins?

I see on [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111550/what-is-the-core-difference-between-coin-and-token) they are referred to as `coins` but is that the standard or are other words used?

I am trying to name a function that gets these `coins`.

Comment: you mean the nativ currency of the chain? . each chain has its own coin or native currency and it is used to pay gas and do other stuff. I think on Ethereum based blockchain (like Ethereum, BSC ... ) they are all called "ether" in source-code.

Comment: @MajdTL Would it be correct to refer to them as ether, or is ether strictly Ethereum based? Like, did the devs just didn't change the name in the source?

Comment: they probably didn't even change the name in the source code. I think they change it only in the frontend. 
https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/search?q=ether

Answer (score 0):

A `coin` is the medium of providing security/consensus, rewarding miners/stakers, and paying for transaction fees/gas in blockchain networks, and is inherent to a specific chain. A coin is deployed on the base (core) layer of the blockchain. Examples are Ether (ETH) on Ethereum, BTC on Bitcoin, XMR on Monero, or ADA on Cardano.

Contrast this with a `token`, which is a contractually controlled medium of accounting or utility used for specific protocols. Tokens are deployed on the application layer of the network. Tokens can be a programmatic representation of another asset (ex. USDC or WBTC), used for protocol governance (ex. MKR, UNI, AAVE), providing utility or performing work (ex. LINK, GRT) or just another tradeable asset when paired with liquidity on a blockchain (ex. SHIB, memecoins). Tokens aren't responsible for blockchain-wide utility and interaction with the tokens still requires the canonical token for that blockchain in order to process transaction fees.